# Why is data repeated in Open Office Calc

Tags: xlsx, openoffice-calc

I opened a .xlsx file in open office calc (on my mac) and the data in most of the cells which has numbered list items, is repeated twice.

For example, if a particular cell has numbered list like:

```
1. something
2. something
3. something
```

Then this list will be repeated twice like this:

```
1. something
2. something
3. something
1. something
2. something
3. something
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been driving me crazy. I finally fixed it by saving the file as .xls (97-2004) format in excel prior to opening it in Open Office.

Comment: I had the same problem with duplicate cell data. Saving as .xls (97-2004) solved it for me. Thanks for the solution.